Some doubts on the derivation of $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=+\frac{1}{c}F^{\nu\sigma}J_\sigma$ for particles
From here on, I'll transcribe my professor's derivation and then ask the questions. If the proof is a little vague, it's because I wasn't able to catch the explanation for each step while in class.
To prove that for particles
$$\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}_{\mathrm{part}}=\frac{1}{c}F^{\nu\sigma}J_\sigma$$
holds, we start with the definition of the energy-momentum tensor for particles
$$T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{part}}(\mathrm x)=c\int\,\mathrm d\tau\, U^\mu P^\nu\,\delta^{(4)}(\mathrm x-r(\tau)):$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{part}}(\mathrm x)&=c\int\,\mathrm d\tau\, P^\nu\,\frac{\mathrm dr^\mu}{\mathrm d\tau}\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathrm x^\mu}\delta^{(4)}(\mathrm x-r(\tau));\ \ U^\mu=\frac{\mathrm dr^\mu}{\mathrm d\tau};\ P^\nu=mU^\nu\\
&=c\int\,\mathrm d\tau\, P^\nu\,\frac{\mathrm dr^\mu}{\mathrm d\tau}(-1)\frac{\partial}{\partial r^\mu}\delta^{(4)}(\mathrm x-r(\tau))\\
&=-c\int\,\mathrm d\tau\, P^\nu\,\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\tau}\delta^{(4)}(\mathrm x-r(\tau))\\
&\!\overset{\mathrm{IBP}}{=}+c\int\,\mathrm d\tau\, \frac{\mathrm d P^\nu}{\mathrm d\tau}\,\delta^{(4)}(\mathrm x-r(\tau))\\
&=+c\int\,\mathrm d\tau\, \frac{q}{c}F^{\nu\sigma}U_\sigma\,\delta^{(4)}(\mathrm x-r(\tau))=\frac{1}{c}F^{\nu\sigma}J_\sigma,
\end{aligned}
$$
where in this last step we used the definition of current for a point charge,
$$J^\mu=qc\int\,\mathrm d\tau\, U^\mu\,\delta^{(4)}(\mathrm x-r(\tau)).$$
Questions. Concerning the definition of $T^{\mu\nu}_{\mathrm{part}}(\mathrm x)$, I'm not entirely sure where it comes from. The only notion I have is that in the point charge current equation, according to the professor, if we interpret $q\sim P^\nu_{\mathrm{part}}$ you get this relation.
Moreover, in the second step, I'm not sure where the $-1$ comes from. My suspicion is that it might have to do with a jacobian due to a change of variables or maybe applying chain rule.
At last, in the final step, did he do
$$c\int\,\mathrm d\tau\, \frac{q}{c}F^{\nu\sigma}U_\sigma\,\delta^{(4)}(\mathrm x-r(\tau))=\frac{1}{c}F^{\nu\sigma}\left[qc\int\,\mathrm d\tau\,U_\sigma\,\delta^{(4)}(\mathrm x-r(\tau))\right]=\frac{1}{c}F^{\nu\sigma}J_\sigma\ ?$$
If so, the fact that $F^{\mu\nu}$ is being brought out of the integral, does it imply anything regarding its dependence on $r^\mu$ or $\tau$?

As to the definition of the stress-energy tensor for electromagnetism, it was derived (partially by Maxwell, partially by Poynting) simply as the structure that had to appear as part of the total stress-energy tensor in order for total energy and momentum to be conserved.

First, consider the definition of the particle energy-momentum tensor, $T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{part}}(x)$. You're right to be a bit puzzled; it's not a given, but rather a construction representing the energy and momentum density of a point particle in a relativistic setting. The key idea is that $T^{\mu\nu}$ represents the flux of the $\mu$-th component of momentum in the $\nu$-th direction. For a single particle, we can think of it as a "localized" energy-momentum density. The delta function, $\delta^{(4)}(x-r(\tau))$, is crucial here, ensuring that the energy and momentum are only non-zero at the particle's location, $r(\tau)$, at a given proper time $\tau$. The components are: $P^\nu$, the particle's four-momentum; $U^\mu = \frac{dr^\mu}{d\tau}$, the particle's four-velocity; $c$, the speed of light; and $\int d\tau$, the integral over the particle's worldline. The product $U^\mu P^\nu$ relates to the flux of momentum, the delta function localizes this flux, and the integral sums over the trajectory. Your professor's comment about $q \sim P^\nu_{\text{part}}$ is an analogy, not a direct substitution. The current density $J^\mu$ relates to the flow of charge, and $T^{\mu\nu}$ to the flow of energy and momentum, both localized by the delta function.
Regarding the minus sign in the second step, it arises from the chain rule and the fact that we're differentiating with respect to $x^\mu$ while the delta function depends on $x - r(\tau)$. We have $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\delta^{(4)}(x-r(\tau))$. Thinking of the delta function as a function of $y^\mu = x^\mu - r^\mu(\tau)$, the chain rule gives us
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} \delta^{(4)}(x-r(\tau)) = \frac{\partial \delta^{(4)}(y)}{\partial y^\nu} \frac{\partial y^\nu}{\partial x^\mu}. $$
Since $\frac{\partial y^\nu}{\partial x^\mu} = \frac{\partial (x^\nu - r^\nu(\tau))}{\partial x^\mu} = \delta^\nu_\mu$, we have
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} \delta^{(4)}(x-r(\tau)) = \frac{\partial \delta^{(4)}(y)}{\partial y^\mu}. $$
On the other hand, $\frac{\partial}{\partial r^\mu} \delta^{(4)}(x-r(\tau)) = \frac{\partial \delta^{(4)}(y)}{\partial y^\nu} \frac{\partial y^\nu}{\partial r^\mu}$, and since $\frac{\partial y^\nu}{\partial r^\mu} = \frac{\partial (x^\nu - r^\nu(\tau))}{\partial r^\mu} = -\delta^\nu_\mu$, we get
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial r^\mu} \delta^{(4)}(x-r(\tau)) = -\frac{\partial \delta^{(4)}(y)}{\partial y^\mu}. $$
Therefore,
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} \delta^{(4)}(x-r(\tau)) = - \frac{\partial}{\partial r^\mu} \delta^{(4)}(x-r(\tau)). $$
This minus sign is a direct consequence of the chain rule and the delta function's argument being the difference between $x$ and $r(\tau)$.
Finally, in the last step, the professor is indeed doing
$$ c\int d\tau \frac{q}{c} F^{\nu\sigma}U_\sigma \delta^{(4)}(x-r(\tau)) = \frac{1}{c} F^{\nu\sigma} \left[ qc \int d\tau U_\sigma \delta^{(4)}(x-r(\tau)) \right] = \frac{1}{c} F^{\nu\sigma} J_\sigma. $$
The fact that $F^{\nu\sigma}$ is brought out of the integral implies that it is evaluated at the same spacetime point as the particle, i.e., at $x^\mu = r^\mu(\tau)$. In other words, $F^{\nu\sigma}$ is a function of $x$, and we are evaluating it at the particle's position. This is a crucial assumption, meaning that the force on the particle at a given time is determined by the electromagnetic field at the particle's location at that time, which is the essence of the Lorentz force law in a relativistic context.

Really complete and well redacted explanations; you solved all my questions, thank you!
